# Calling .click() in a file input field brings up file browser but doesn't fill in path

Tags: jquery, html, forms, file-upload, input

I have the following jquery call activated when I click on a picture button:

```
$("#photo_input").click();
```

In IE9, it brings up the file browser. However, when I select a file, it does not change the path. Thus, my onchange function never calls, and the form is not submitted. Here's the html for the input field:

```
<input style = 'display:block' type = 'file' name = 'newPicture' id = 'photo_input' onchange = 'manual_photo_upload()'/>
```

The function it calls only has one line:

```
$("#manual_photo_form").submit();
```

Basically, all I want is for the user to click on a picture button to upload a file. Whether I set display on the input field to block or none, it's the same story. What can be done to solve this?

Comment: I think **Style =** create the problem in your input tag. Just remove it and then try.

Comment: That was actually just an error in posting. I've edited it to reflect what I'm actually using.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `onchange` attribute and using jQuery to handle the event instead:

```
$('#photo_input').change(function() {
    $("#manual_photo_form").submit();
});
```

Comment: Removing the onchange and using that makes it fill in the path, but it doesn't submit the form.